# Spring Cloud Gateway - Proxy for route

Tags: proxy, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

I use the Spring Cloud Gateway to route incoming requests to different targets. I can rewrite the paths, set different authentication methods; but I can't find a way to define route-specific proxy settings. How can the following scenario be solved:

- Incoming request A -> route A matched -> just forward to target
  system
- Incoming request B -> route B matched -> set proxy for target
  system call -> forward to target system using the proxy

The proxy parameters are provided by another service that is injected in route definition.

Do you have any idea/ link/ code snippet how to solve that issue? Any hint is welcome.

Thanks.

Regards
Karsten